# How to read a file, convert letters, and print string and integers to an array in c?

Tags: arrays, c, file

```
struct reviewStruct {
  char reviewer[50];
  int feedback[3];
};

int readReviews(FILE *file, struct reviewStruct reviews[10]) {

  int i;
  file = fopen("Names.txt", "r");
  if(file == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(-1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fgets(reviews[i].reviewer, 50, file);
  }
  
  fclose(file);

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s", reviews[i].reviewer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> Hello, I'm trying to read a file line by line and print it to an array, with a catch. Whenever a 'Y' or 'y' appears, it converts that letter into a 1, and if an 'N' or 'n' appears, it is converted into a 0 (zero), excluding the first word of every line. For example, I have a file with the following information:

```
charlie Y n N
priya N n Y
lance y y Y
stan N y n
arin N n N
```

> This is the text file called Names.txt, I want to save the integer information to the array called "feedback", so that it looks like this when printed using a for loop:

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

> How do I populate the feedback array such that it can be printed along with the names using a for loop as it is in the following image?

```
charlie 1 0 0
priya 0 0 1
lance 1 1 1
stan 0 1 0
arin 0 0 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the file contents into the question as code, instead of linking to a picture.

Comment: You wrote the following in the question: "Whenever a 'Y' or 'y' appears, it converts that letter into a 1" Does that mean that the `y` in `priya` should also be converted to a `1`? Or should the first word in the line be ignored?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I should have made that more clear, the first word in each line should be ignored yes, just the letters that are after the names.

Comment: The problem can be solved with either `fscanf` or `fgets`. If you decide to use `fgets`, then you can use the function `strtok` to split the string, but you can also do it without the help of that function. Generally, I don't recommend using the function `fscanf` or `scanf` because it offers very limited input validation (verifying that the input is correct), but you seem to be allowed to assume that the input is always valid, so that is not an issue in your case. Therefore, please show us your attempt of using `fscanf` or `fgets`, and we will tell you what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Comment: In the code you have posted, you seem to have succeeded in reading in 10 lines of the file. Now all that is left is to examine the line contents. As already stated, you can use `strtok` for this, but you can also solve it without `strtok`.

Comment: Note that it is generally a good idea to check the return value of the function `fgets`, in order to ensure that the function was successful. For example, the function will fail if it is unable to read any more data, due to reaching the end of the file.